# How to enable/retrieve SD drive

Tags: sd-card

I was trying to safely remove the SD card from my sister's "I" drive and instead of hitting "eject"  I hit "safely remove hardware" and it deleted the entire drive! I'm freaking out.  Is there a way I can recover the drive? I went into Device Manager and it's not there for me to try to enable. And when I put the SD card back in the drive, it doesn't read it.

Answer (score 3):

Some devices have both options and for some reason, when you choose `Safely Remove Hardware` it looses the drive letter (but does not format).

Sometimes just taking out and putting it back is enough, but it sounds like you have tried that.

Please try the following:

Go to computer management (Right click Computer / My Computer), then click "Manage"

"Expand Storage" > "Disk Management", and right click on the drive you wish to change.

Click on "Change Drive Letter and Paths" and click Add.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Do Assign Letter, not mount in a folder!)

Comment: William answer is correct.